# Write a function file that returns the sum of the positive components and the sum of the negative components of the input vector

Tags: matlab, vector, sum, components

**Question:** Write a function file that returns the sum of the positive components and the sum of the negative components of the input vector.

This problem has to be done in MATLAB but I am completely new in MATLAB? Can anyone give idea how to do this?

**Attempts:**

```
V= input(Enter a vector) 
function [Ps, Ns] = mysmallfunction(V)
Ps== sum(V(V>0));
Ns= sum(V(V<0));
end
```

I don't know whether it will work or not.

Comment: "I don't know whether it will work or not." Why not run it and see? That is the only way you can learn to program. Try and fail, try and fail again, and again, until you succeed.

Comment: Note that `==` is _comparison_. Use `=` for _assignment_.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much had it. Below is a script that'll guide you through passing the arguments and calling the function. A small issue was the double `==` for the assignment of `Ps` within the function (simply use one `=` unless it's for a conditional statement). To call/test the function simply use the line `[Ps, Ns] = mysmallfunction(V);` above your function definition (alternatively can put function definitions in separate scripts).

```
V = input("Enter a vector: ");

%Function call%
[Ps, Ns] = mysmallfunction(V);

%Printing the results to the command window%
fprintf("The positive numbers sum up to %f\n",Ps);
fprintf("The negative numbers sum up to %f\n",Ns);


%*******************************************************************************************************%
%FUNCTION DEFINITION (this can alternatively go in a separate script named: mysmallfunction.m)%
%*******************************************************************************************************%

function [Ps, Ns] = mysmallfunction(V)
    Ps = sum(V(V>0));
    Ns = sum(V(V<0));
end
```

---

### Command Window (sample input)

Important to include the square brackets, `[]` in this case when inputting the vector.

> Enter a vector: [1 2 3 -2 -5]